# Are SysV Semaphores represented within the filesystem?

Tags: c, key, shared-memory, semaphore

Does a call to `semget()` result in the creation of a unique file somewhere in the filesystem? I'm attempting to use a semaphore as the key to a shared memory segment and thought ftok() might be a viable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. System V IPC objects (semaphores, message queues, and shared memory) exist in a separate namespace from the filesystem.